# Catch user name and document name when list item or library item is click

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-addin, designer-workflow

I trying to create a logic either using SharePoint JSOM and jQuery/JavaScript that will execute whenever a user tries to open a document and force user to acknowledge the document and record the acknowledgement based on the user confirmation. acknowledgement record will be captured in List available on the same SharePoint site.

Lets say, the user go to the library and lick on one of the policies, I would to have a windows prompt asking the user to acknowledge the document.

A colleague of mine implemented something similar in the past for a employee handbook. I was able to get the java scripts he used but I cant seem figure it out.

> > here is what I'm trying to accomplish.

1. User click to open a document on a SharePoint library
2. A window prompt open and ask the user to acknowledge that they have read the document.
3. user click OK and the windows prompt close and document open
4. User name and document name/tile is save to a List.

Any help or if there is a better way to accomplish the same would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The process for creating an alert for an individual item and not the whole list or library is pretty easy.

Click on Check box next to file or item you want to create SharePoint alert for. On the ribbon, now, select the tab on the left (file or item). Then choose Select an Alert on this document and from there just follow the steps as outlined above.

Comment: Hey Mathew, I'm not trying to create an alert on the library item. I trying to create a logic to force user to acknowledge some policy we have on a library and save the acknowledgement information to a list.

Lets say, the user go to the library and lick on one of the policies, I would to have a windows prompt asking the user to acknowledge the document.

A colleague of mine implemented something similar in the past for a employee handbook. I was able to get the java scripts he used but I cant seem figure it out.